# Using javascript:history.go(-1) works but I lose css properties and scripts

Tags: javascript, css, forms, back, browser-history

When my clients submit a form and get an error they're taken to a page with a link to go back.  I'm using javascript:history.go(-1) to go back to the form.

I'm loosing my css functionality with background changes and colors, etc. of the form when the client goes back.

I don't want the client to have to re-type everything agian with a refresh.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Do you mean that when the client goes back, the page has absolutely no CSS? Also, please include some code.

Comment: please, include the browser(s) you tested this

Comment: Why don't you just take them to the form and display the error messages and repopulate the fields, why are you giving them a link to go back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you save all the Data entered in the PHP Session, and (instead of history.go(-1)) Place a link to the Form again, where you check if there are values in the session, and write them in the Form-Field with PHP?

Something like

```
$_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name']
```

and backwards..

You could even do that without showing an error Page, and displaying the error on the form itself...

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS you mention is being entered as part of the form, you might check out using a shim like [Sisyphus.js](http://simsalabim.github.com/sisyphus/) to ensure cross-browser persistence when your user steps back through the form.